# python string to list with delimiter

Tags: python

Cant post the picture so i'll describe it as precise as possible:

- 001.txt contains ->  a b c ...
- 002.txt contains ->  d e f ...
- 003.txt contains ->  g h i ...
- etc.

---

- 001 002 003
- a----d----g
- b----e----h
- c----f-----i

the data from above should look like a chart in the end in Excel (.csv)

My skills are very very limited or not even there.
Maybe someone here to give me a fast explanation or some type of help. First time chatter so dont be to hard on me :D

started to code something like this

```
with open("001.txt", "r") as f, open("002.txt", "r") as f, open("003.txt") as f:
lines = f.read().split(',')

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

---

My solution thanks to AKX

```
import csv

filelist = ["001.txt", "002.txt", "003.txt"]
destinationfile = "meine.csv"
dictionary = {}

for file in filelist:
    split = file.split(".", 1)
    header = split[0]
    readfile = open(file, "r")
    tlist = []
    for line in readfile:
        split_line = line.split()
        for split in split_line:
            tlist.append(split)
    dictionary.update({header: tlist})

with open(destinationfile, "w", newline='') as csv_file:
     writer = csv.writer(csv_file,dialect='excel',delimiter=";")
     headers = list(dictionary)
     writer.writerow(headers)
     for entry in zip(*dictionary.values()):
         writer.writerow(entry)
```

Comment: This will not work, as multiple files/streams are saved with the same variable (`f`) and therefore only the last one (`003.txt`) will be readed. In addition there are indentation errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat hard to tell whether `a`, `b`, `c` etc. are separate lines in each file, so I'm not quite able to help with the file-reading code.

However, you can use the `zip(*...)` idiom to transpose lists of values.

Assuming all of your files are the same length, once you have loaded the text from the files into a dict as below, you can do the printing with

```
data = {"001": ["a", "b", "c"], "002": ["d", "e", "f"], "003": ["g", "h", "i", "j"]}

headers = list(data)
print(*headers)
for row in zip(*data.values()):
    print(*row)
```

– the output is

```
001 002 003
a d g
b e h
c f i
```

If the data isn't the same length, you can use `zip_longest` from `itertools`:

```
for row in itertools.zip_longest(*data.values(), fillvalue="-"):
    print(*row)
```

and the output is

```
001 002 003
a d g
b e h
c f i
- - j
```

Comment: Why sort the headers at all? With just the headers sorted but not the values, you're more than likely going to end up with values under the wrong headers. The output in your example is correct only because the given headers from the OP happen to be already sorted.

Comment: Good point, my bad. Removed the sorted call (on mobile), but another sorted/zip call would fix that up.

Comment: i got three .txt files with a,b,c/d,e,f/g,h,i written in them. Your answer got all the data in the code itself. I am trying to read the files to get the output like a chart

Comment: @papapixxel You likely know how to assign to a dict, and you know how to read a file to a list - combine that with my answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
filelist = ["001.txt", "002.txt", "003.txt"]
destinationfile = "ergebnis.csv"
print(filelist)
for file in filelist:
    print(file)
    readfile = open(file, "r")
    print(readfile.read())
```

How about something like this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).